# Temporal GLMM - advice

Tags: r, correlation, glmm

I am new to temporal analyses and hoping for some constructive advise/criticism.

My data are monthly counts of animal carcasses submitted to a laboratory for disease testing. I have made the data [accessible here](https://universityofadelaide.box.com/s/p7911mo3sgyv15wkrc6prhxbp26kbej5) so that others might pick up on important considerations I have not. The data range is approximately January 1st 2016 - December 1st 2019, but some months are missing.

My goal is to investigate if the submission of animal carcasses is influenced by the season of submission (summer/autumn/winter/spring), Australian state (8 states), animal source (domestic vs wild animal) or if the data show evidence for submission trends through time.

Being count data I had planned to build a GLMM in the `glmmTMB` package with `family = poisson`. However, I am unsure how I should be accounting for the temporal aspect of the data?

I believe the basic components of the model would be as follows, but how should date of submission be included? Should I be looking to include some sort of correlation structure?

`glmmTMB(n ~ season + state + source, data = dat, family = poisson)`

I note that Ben Bolker has written a post on [fitting mixed models with (temporal) correlations in R](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/notes/corr_braindump.html), however a lot of this I did not follow. Any thoughts/feedback would be greatly appreciated.